# androidTestImplementation gives an error with newer version of test runner

Tags: android-studio-3.0

When I create a new project in android studio it gives this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>
> > Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app
> >     (27.1.1) differ. See
> >     https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for
> >     details.

If I change `com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2` to 
`com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1` and `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2` to `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1` on **build.gradle(Module:app)** the errors are disappearing.How to solve this problem ? I don't want to change it in every project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line into dependencies of build.gradle(app module)

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 0):

This resolved it for me:

- Upgrade compileSdkVersion to
  `compileSdkVersion 27`
- Change `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` to `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

Comment: How to Upgrade `compileSdkVersion to compileSdkVersion 27`? I changed `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` to `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` . But now it's showing `This support library should not use a different version (27) than the compileSdkVersion (26)`